# Regression output from R to latex from zim model

Tags: r, function, latex

I'm trying to get my results from R to latex. I have different regression output from a `zim()` model (`library(ZIM)`). My output is `class() zim`, therefore, `stargazer` or `xtable` don't work.

I'm trying to build a function to do it, but I'm not sure how to do it. The farthest I have reach is to extract `se` and `coefficients` and create a list of coef1, se1, coef2, se2, and so on. But I want 5-6 models in the same table, so it is taking me a long time.

```
standard_errors <- m1$se
coefficients <- m1$para
coef <- c( "","Constant","NO2","Admissions lag","Trend",         
           "Constant","NO2","Admissions lag","Trend" )

table_data2 <- data.frame(
  Variable = coef,
  Coefficient = coefficients,
  SE = standard_errors
)

tbk1 <- data.frame(
  
  Coefficient = coefficients,
  SE = standard_errors
)
tbk1$Coefficient <- round(tbk1$Coefficient, 3)
tbk1$SE <- round(tbk1$SE, 3)

tbl1<-as.data.frame(matrix(t(tbk1), ncol= ncol(tbk1)/2, byrow=TRUE,
                          dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1"))))
```

I tried to share my output (`dput()`) but it is too big and can't be shared.

If I ask for `summary(m1)` I get the list of elements in `m1`, but not the output, the output is generated by just running `m1`.

```
              Length Class  Mode   
iter             1   -none- numeric
gradient         9   -none- numeric
info            81   -none- numeric
para             9   -none- numeric
se               9   -none- numeric
loglik           1   -none- numeric
aic              1   -none- numeric
bic              1   -none- numeric
tic              1   -none- numeric
call             3   -none- call   
control         10   -none- list   
na.action        3   omit   numeric
y             1259   -none- numeric
X             5036   -none- numeric
Z             5036   -none- numeric
k                1   -none- numeric
lambda        1259   -none- numeric
omega         1259   -none- numeric
fitted.values 1259   -none- numeric
residuals     1259   -none- numeric
```

How can I generate a regression output ready for latex putting together my 5-6 outputs?